# pause() from audio library not working in r project

Tags: r, wav, wave

After using play() function the sound plays continuously. How do I stop it. The code below shows that I used the pause() function but that just gives me an error message, I've also tried using close() function.

```
> pause(saw)
Error in UseMethod("pause") : 
  no applicable method for 'pause' applied to an object of class "c('Wave', 'WaveGeneral')"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you use these two different packages:

- `tuneR` to import your wave file
- `audio`for its playback functions

Unfortunately these packages each have their own object classes: `Wave` class in `tuneR` and `audioSample` class in `audio`. If you want to use the playback functions of `audio` you first need an object of class `audioSample`. You can get this by importing your wave file with audio's own import function

```
mywav <- load.wave("myaudiosample.wav")
```

but since `tuneR` can also import mp3 files and has more import options it may be necessary to create your own `audioSample` object manually from a `Wave` object. A simple mono file for example could be converted the following way:

```
myWave <- readWave("myaudiosample.wav")
mywav <- audioSample(myWave@left, myWave@samp.rate, myWave@bit)
```

You can then use the playback functions from `audio`. Just make sure to call `audio::play()`, it might be masked by `tuneR`

```
a <- audio::play(mywav)
pause(a)
resume(a)
```